# Problem using a local variable in a SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, local-variables

I have this SQL statement:

```
SELECT DNI, puntaje, @row := @row+1 as Puesto
FROM postulante, (SELECT @row := 0) r
WHERE idCa = 2 
  AND idPer = 1 
  AND @row <= (SELECT vacantes 
                FROM carrera_abierta 
                WHERE idCa=2 AND idPer=1)
ORDER BY puntaje DESC ;
```

I want to limit the rows returned by a column value. But when I run:
[It doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4F0T.png):

[image]

[Of course the result of the subquery is a small value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyFdu.png):
[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT DNI, puntaje, @row := @row+1 as Puesto
      FROM postulante, (SELECT @row := 0) r
      WHERE idCa = 2 
        AND idPer = 1 
      ORDER BY puntaje DESC) sub
WHERE Puesto <= (SELECT vacantes 
                FROM carrera_abierta 
                WHERE idCa=2 AND idPer=1)
ORDER BY Puesto;
```

Comment: @Vicious & LukaszSzozda In MySQL reading & writing the same variable in a SELECT statement is not defined. See the manual. People from Percona have shown by examining the implementation code that certain expressions using CASE in a SELECT clause happen to work in the "current" implementation--whenever that was.